# Is it correct to join the same table multiple times on different conditions?

Tags: sql, styles

I'm building a simple app based on a moodle (2.4) database. The db is mysql 5.1.69

I need to find all certs granted this month and all relevant information about the user that got the cert and the cert itself.

My sql as it stands is:

```
SELECT u.lastname, u.firstname, ln.data, lt.data, course.fullname,
    c.printhours, from_unixtime(i.timecreated) AS issued,
    substring_index(c.customtext, ' ', -1) AS approval
FROM mdl_certificate_issues AS i
INNER JOIN mdl_certificate AS c ON i.certificateid = c.id
INNER JOIN mdl_user AS u on i.userid = u.id
INNER JOIN mdl_course AS course ON c.course = course.id
INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data AS ln ON i.userid = ln.userid AND ln.fieldid = 1
INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data AS lt ON i.userid = lt.userid AND lt.fieldid = 2
WHERE i.timecreated >= unix_timestamp('2013-07-01')
    AND i.timecreated < unix_timestamp('2013-08-01')
```

The fact that I'm joining the same table (mdl_user_info_data) twice (as lt and ln) and using the same columns, but differing only on the fieldid is what bothers me. It feels like I should be able to do that in a single subquery and pull the correct information into the select - but I just can't figure out how to do it, or if that is even the correct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the approach you have. Personally I always pick join over subquery, I'd probably pick more meaningful aliases than "ln" and "lt", though

Comment: For some reason it seems to be difficult to find straightforward sql style advice when there are multiple ways to do something - so many thanks.

Comment: Join versus subquery is generally more of an optimisation question, than style. Though most DBMS's will have a go at converting a subquery to a join nowadays.